# Преобразование типов

Tags: haskell

У меня функция путём нехитрых манипуляций получает строку типа IO [String], а мне нужен String. Например, вывести на экран.
Как производить преобразование типов?

Comment: `IO [String]` — это не строка, а список строк в IO монаде.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример — программа, которая конкатенирует свои аргументы:

```
import System.Environment

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    putStrLn $ concat args
```

Тип `getArgs :: IO [String]`.

Напишем функцию `f`:

```
f :: Monad m => m [[a]] -> m [a]
f m = m >>= (\ xs -> return $ concat xs)
```

Развернем `do` нотацию в оригинальном примере:

```
main :: IO ()
main = (f getArgs) >>= putStrLn
```

- [`getArgs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/System-Environment.html#v:getArgs)
- [`concat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat)
- [`(>>=)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-)
- [`putStrLn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn)
- [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle)
- Посмотреть тип функции в ghci:

  ```
  :t functionName
  ```